# connecting tor over ssh error Socks proxy failed to connect, error 4 (host unreachable)

Tags: torsocks, error, raspberry-pi, ssh

I already had setup hidden service on my pi4 and it was working just fine until I decided that I'd install the same config on another sd card and from then on it gives me the same error again and again "  Socks proxy failed to connect, error 4 (host unreachable) " I have tried everything from checking if the configuration is right to enabling the port using ufw, iptables, firewalld to trying to setup a new hidden service but it always gives me the same error and neither can I see a fix on the web nor can I fix it myself.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details, such as the tor logs from the client and server. Another thing you can do is enable `ExtendedErrors` in your client's torrc file (see `man tor`) to get a better socks error message about why the connection is failing.